# How to load a url link that is inside a web view and keep it in that web view in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a web view that has a webpage with links at the bottom. I have a way to deal with them being clicked, but all it does is open them into a new safari browser. This is not what I want.I would like for them to stay inside the web view and allow me to navigate them easily like that. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried just using a regular web view, but then the links at the bottom will not work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var myWebview: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var returnButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    prettyReturnButton(returnButton)

    let url = NSURL(string: "mywebpage")

    myWebview.delegate = self

    print("Web page:" , url)
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    myWebview.loadRequest(requestObj);
    myWebview.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = true



}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    switch navigationType {
    case .LinkClicked:
        // Open links in Safari
        //let newRequestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: request.URL!)
       // webView.loadRequest(newRequestObj)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
        return false
    default:
        // Handle other navigation types...
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: it supposed navigate to links within the same webview if you not using delegate

Comment: If you don't want the links opened in Safari, then why do you intercept the links and open them in Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the webview delegate you are going to want to navigate to the new url using that same webview.

For you this means that inside your switch case you should use
 `loadRequest`

[loadRequest documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617957-loadrequest)

To fix your issue you should remove the line using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)`

and replace it with a call to `loadRequest`

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    switch navigationType {

    case .LinkClicked:
        // Open links in Safari

        guard let newRequest = request as? URLRequest else { return false }

        webView.loadRequest(newRequest)
        return false
    default:
        // Handle other navigation types...
        return true
   }
}
```

Hope this helps! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Give delegates to your UIViewcontroller : `UIWebViewDelegate`

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.djmazacool.com")
 let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
 YOURWEBVIEW.delegate = self
 YOURWEBVIEW.loadRequest(req)



func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{
        // start animation
        print("start loaded call")
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{
        // load url complete
        print("loading done call")
}
```

Output :

[image: Its my webView Output load url]

**Don't Forgot to add this attribute in .plist file.**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image: .plist file code]