# facebook login through UIWebview using swfit shows blank

Tags: ios, swift, webview, facebook-login

I have a simple ios app that displays a website using WebView. The website has the option to login using facebook. If I navigated that website using a web browser and login using FB, it works fine, however, when I login to that website through my IOS app using a webview, all I get is a blank page after login.

I am using Swift as my language (and I am very new to this that is why I only use a webview instead of building the whole app using native app), and I have looked around and couldn't find the current solution, and didn't work, perhaps because the examples I have seen using objective-C instead of swift?

I have installed the facebook SDK and followed the instructions according to their docs, but again, all examples are login through a native app instead of webview. So, after I installed the FDK and added the frameworks, I don't know how to connect it to my code.

Below is my code to load the webpage if anyone knows a simple solution based on the code below that would be awesome!:

```
@IBOutlet var Webview: UIWebView!

var URLPath = "http://myfactdomain.com"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    loadAddressURL()
}

func loadAddressURL() {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
    Webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have missing webviewdelagates method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40145732/6656894 refer this answer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing this in your info.plist, go to your info.plist and add this, you need this whenever your app needs to load a third party web url.

[image]

Code:

```
    @IBOutlet var fbWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let fbURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: fbURL! as URL)
    fbWebView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}
```

Comment: I do have these settings in the info.plist. And in your code, the fbURL is pointing to facebook page insted of my own page, is that just a place holder?

Comment: could this be caused by facebook opening a second window?