# NSURL WebView not loading

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

My WebView is not loading just blank white here is my code

```
//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  Bachelmatt Garage
//
//  Created by Thilo Jaeggi on 24.05.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Thilo Jaeggi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = URL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com");
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(request);
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I already asked the same question a year ago and heard that i somehow need to enable a "security setting" in Xcode is this the same case here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you added the nstransportsecurity in your plist

Comment: Did you bind the webView to Xib or Storyboard?

Comment: Could you show me how to do that Anbu.Karthik?

Comment: @Zarkex refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40145732/6656894

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a url link that is inside a web view and keep it in that web view in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144923/how-to-load-a-url-link-that-is-inside-a-web-view-and-keep-it-in-that-web-view-in)

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following line in your info.plist(open as source code) file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

For more info please check this [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open your info.plist as SourceCode and add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Then do as mentioned below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")!))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well It is working perfectly: See the below code:

```
import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD

class ConditionsViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webVw: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading")

        webVw.delegate = self

        let url = URL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com");
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
        webVw.loadRequest(request);
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
```

[image] [image]

**Edited**

```
import UIKit
   // import SVProgressHUD

    class ConditionsViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var webVw: UIWebView!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading")

            webVw.delegate = self

            let url = URL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com");
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
            webVw.loadRequest(request);
        }

        func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

            //SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            print("Loaded")

// Here it will print 2-3 sec later, in that mean time your page will load in your view controller
        }
```

Mainly I have added `UIWebViewDelegate` and its delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` . well try it, it will work definitely .

Comment: How did you made that Loading thing??

Comment: No such Module SVProgressHUD

Comment: Don't worry about `SVProgressHUD` it is an third party class. without it do that..

Comment: Ok so i installed SVProgressHUD with Pod but it still says no such module here is my Podfile:

Comment: `SVProgressHUD ` isn't required here, its okay if you not give here, look my edited code. it may help you.

Comment: I know but i want SVProgressHUD :)

Comment: :D, it's okay but it is a different thing, your question is about loading the web page in webview, which is working and it take little time like 2-3 sec to load the entire page.

Comment: if you have installed pods correctly then in your projectfolder few new files has been added, amongst them you can find yourprojectname.xcworkspace, open it, and now import it to your required class like i have done.

Comment: show me your code, and make sure that you had opened .xcworkspace.

Comment: add `webView.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad` and use the delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` please see my code, if you copy paste, it will work.

Comment: Noo the Webpage loading works at all but the Aniamted Loading thing cant be found.