# Delete cache of app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to delete the cache of my app.
I want to show a web page by using UIWebView.

MY current code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!
    webBrowser:(UIWebView *)webBrowser shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
        self.webBrowser.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

When I added this code

```
webBrowser:(UIWebView *)webBrowser shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
```

to ViewController,so "Expected declaration" error happen.
What is wrong in my code?
Should I connect my Storyboard and this code in some point?
How can i fix this?

Comment: The line `webBrowser:(UIWebView *)webBrowser shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` you added, it's a Objective-C code. Convert it in the swift and run the code again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40145732/6656894 refer this answer @user8080149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete cache try below code

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
```

Else you can also change the cache policy of the NSURLRequest

```
let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!,
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
self.webBrowser.loadRequest(day_url_request)
```

it's Objective C code.Update your code like below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
        self.webBrowser.delegate = self
        self.webBrowser.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, 
       shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
         navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
         // do your stuffs
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: thx,ur comments.I have a question about ur code.
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, 
       shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
         navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
         // do your stuffs
    }
of ur code is the part of deleting cache,right?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Objective-C` code `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`

Here is the swift version code to load `UIWebView`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var webBrowser: UIWebView!

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        webBrowser = UIWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        webBrowser.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(webBrowser)
        if let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webBrowser.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }
}
```